# Entity Framework 6 not inserting record?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add a record to my database using EF. I could have sworn this was working and then I put it into production and found it not actually working. When trying to test locally now it's not working there either. I'm not getting any errors in my logs. However, when I look at the DB the record is not there. It looks correct to me. I even tried both methods to add to my entity. I'm looking for any suggestions?

This is using EF for Oracle but I don't think that's an issue.

```
public static void InsertRecord(EmployeePaySheet employeePaySheet)
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        ABSMGMT_CREW_HOURS newCrewPay = new ABSMGMT_CREW_HOURS();
        newCrewPay.RID = 0;
        newCrewPay.EMP_NAME = employeePaySheet.EmployeeName;
        newCrewPay.EMP_ID = employeePaySheet.EmployeeId;
        newCrewPay.POSITION = employeePaySheet.Position;
        newCrewPay.PAY_CATEGORY = employeePaySheet.PayCategory;
        newCrewPay.PAY_RATE = employeePaySheet.PayRate;
        newCrewPay.PAY_CODE = employeePaySheet.PayCode;
        newCrewPay.PAY_HOURS = employeePaySheet.PayHours;
        newCrewPay.PAY_AMOUNT = employeePaySheet.PayAmount;
        newCrewPay.INSERT_DATE = System.DateTime.Now;

        db.ABSMGMT_CREW_HOURS.Add(newCrewPay);
        //db.Entry(newCrewPay).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

        db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Entity

```
public partial class ABSMGMT_CREW_HOURS
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal? RID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string EMP_ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string EMP_NAME { get; set; }

        [StringLength(3)]
        public string PAY_CATEGORY { get; set; }

        public decimal? PAY_RATE { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string PAY_CODE { get; set; }

        public decimal? PAY_HOURS { get; set; }

        public decimal? PAY_AMOUNT { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public string MONTH_YEAR { get; set; }

        public DateTime INSERT_DATE { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5)]
        public string POSITION { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of ABSMGMT_CREW_HOURS Entity?

Comment: Added to the original post now.

Comment: The key is a nullable decimal? I dont think any RDBMS allows that.

Comment: I agree, it's shouldn't be nullable. I removed the "?" so that it just says decimal now but unfortunately that didn't seem to make a difference. What's even crazier is that because I have the System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine set I can see the SQL statement in the OUTPUT and the query looks like it should work.

Comment: you are setting key to 0 each time you try to add a new record - newCrewPay.RID = 0;

Comment: Thanks for looking and trying to give me a hand. I found the problem. Our DBA just recently switch the DB schema but left the old schema in place. So, inserts were going to one schema and I was querying an different schema. Ughhh....at least I know the code is correct. I need to change everything to point to the right place and it should all work. I found that by looking at the SQL query it was displaying. It took me a few minutes to see it but I finally found it.

Comment: Also, yes, I'm setting the RID to 0 because that's what the Oracle trigger is looking for to create the PK. This is Oracle 11.....gotta love me some Oracle.